# NodeJS: localhost keeps loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im using NodeJS to serve some files but the page keeps on loading.
Here is my `index.js` file.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const socketio = require("socket.io");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("server listening to port: " + PORT);
});
```

This is my public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="media-video">
        <video id="media-camera" autoplay="autoplay" playsinline>

        </video>
        <video id="media-remote-video" autoplay="autoplay" playsinline>

        </video>
        <video id="media-screen-capture" autoplay="autoplay" playsinline>

        </video>
        <select name="video" id="media-video-devices">
            <option value="None">None</option>
        </select>
        <select name="audio" id="media-audio-devices">
            <option value="None">None</option>
        </select>
        <button id="start-media-stream">Start Stream</button>
        <button id="end-media-stream">End Stream</button>
        <button id="start-media-screen-capture">Capture Screen</button>
        <button id="end-media-screen-capture">End screen capture</button>
    </div>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The page load perfectly including the all JS and css files but still locahost:3000 keeps on loading.

Comment: Try `app.listen` instead of `server.listen`.

Comment: i want to use socket.io as well so I'm listening on server instead of app.

Comment: Your code looks correct, i've recreated locally and it loads for me. Maybe you have some odd process listening in 3000. Did you check `ps -a | grep node`

Comment: but you still need to return a response back to the user, else the server hangs until it times out.

Comment: @uke I tried that command it return nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is "hanging" because you are not sending a response back to the user. The code just serves the middleware express static files but then you are not handling the request/response cycle...

This is an example of what you could do:

```
// require http native node api...

var http = require('http');

// initialize express...here the server is not listening
// your files are not served yet...

var app = require('express')();

// this is the middleware that serves your static files
// the css and js come from this...

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));

// now you create the server using the HTTP module
// passing express as function and the PORT you have set...
// this is listening, not handling your request/response cycle...

http.createServer(app).listen(PORT);

// this is an example of how you end a request response cycle 
// by sending a file back, it could be other things...

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("index.js");       
});
```

Comment: but I want to serve up an entire directory which includes index.html, js ans css file which is why i choose using expess.static()

Comment: there is some confusion here. Allow me to clarify. Express Statis serves your static files but it does not handle your request response cycle, unless you set it that way. You will still use it in your code, but you need to end the response cycle by sending a response to the client. In my example you are sending a file index.js but it could be other things

Answer (score 0):

Express creates a webserver when it creates a socket server, they are both served from the same port, in this case 3000. To connect to the websocket you need to use socket.io to connect to "ws://localhost:3000" instead of any http request you may be making.

Comment: problem is not with socket.io or webserver and socket server. Page keeps on loading even when all files like html, JS and css files are loaded.